# MS Access - PostgreSQL auto number

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

I have a frontend in ms access and a backend in Postgresql. The database used to be on SQL Server before moving onto Postgresql. Most tables have a column called ID that is an AutoNumber in Access, so it gets the next ID automatically. It used to work fine on simple Access (database started on accdb file) and then when it was moved to SQL server.

After moving to PostgreSQL though the column is now labeled as "Number" in Access and it doesn't give new IDs when a new record is added, this causes a "Primary Key cannot be null" error. The Column ID is set to INTEGER with IDENTITY: Always and an increment of 1. Obviously I cannot alter the table in Access and change number into autonumber because it's read-only as a linked table.

How can I make Ms Access recognize the IDENTIFY column of PostgreSQL as an AutoNumber?

Edit with some more information:
I have a table called Orders and a table called Jobs. Each Order has multiple Jobs and they are connected with an OrderID column. Adding an Order without any Jobs works fine (even though the column is "Number" instead of "AutoNumber" Postgres creates new unique values correctly) The problem comes when I add a Job to that Order, I get "Primary Key cannot be null" error.

I added the Job ID field to be visible on the form and it doesn't have any value while I edit the other columns of the Job form. I used to create a new ID using Me.Dirty = False on the Job adding form, and that's the exact point where the error is reported. So Me.Dirty = False doesn't create a new ID on Postgres, but it creates one just fine on Access or SQL Server.

Comment: I am not sure `PostGRE` can auto increment column data. If not then you can use `DMax(...)+1` to increment by 1 and put the value to primary key field by `VBA` or expression.

Comment: Postgre auto-increments just fine when I add a new order. It takes the next possible ID. The problem is when I add a Job, MS Access increments an autonumber when a record is created, Postgre and SQL Server increment when a record is saved. This is why I used Me.Dirty = False to save the record, before adding further data to the record. SQL Server works fine like that, Postgre doesn't

Comment: I just did a quick test using linked tables in Access connected to PostgreSQL tables defined [like this](https://pastebin.com/5nsBrAg6). It worked fine for an "Order" form with a linked continuous subform to add/edit the related "Jobs". Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].